# Angular 2 custom form control: how to sync touched indicator?

Tags: angular

For my angular 2 application I have a **custom form control** that is hosting an input field. Now it would be awesome if i could get the ng-touched values of the embedded input field and the custom control in sync.

```
<ngWrapperRenderedByAngular class="ng-touched">
     <input class="ng-untouched"></input>
</ngWrapperRenderedByAngular
```